# Difference between output of python librosa.core.stft() and matlab spectrogram(x)

Tags: python, matlab

I am converting a Python code to MATLAB. The Python code, uses the following command:

```
stft_ch = librosa.core.stft(audio_input[:, ch_cnt], n_fft=self._nfft, 
                            hop_length=self._hop_len, win_length=self._win_len, 
                            window='hann')
```

Where `audio_input.shape=(2880000, 4)`, `self._nfft=2048`, `self._hop_len=960` and `self._win_len=1920`.

When converting to MATLAB I used:

```
stft_ch = spectrogram(audio_input(:, ch_cnt), hann(win_len), win_len-hop_len, nfft);
```

where I verified `size(audio_input)=2880000, 4`, `win_len=1920`, `win_len-hop_len=960` and `nfft=2048`.

I am getting an output from MATLAB with `size(stft_ch)=1025, 2999` where Python shows `stft_ch.shape=(1025, 3001)`.  The size `2999` in the MATLAB output is clear and feats the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/spectrogram.html#bultmx7-s) where `k = ⌊(Nx – noverlap)/(length(window) – noverlap)⌋` if window is a vector.

However, I could not find in the [Python documentation](https://librosa.github.io/librosa/generated/librosa.core.stft.html) how is the length of `t` set.

Why is there a difference between sizes? Is my conversion good?

Is there a Python function which produces an output more similar to MATLAB's `spectrogram()` so that I can get the complex output with the same size?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found the answer myself.

The MATLAB function `spectrogram()` outputs a vector of times which corresponds to the middle of each window while omitting the last window. For example, a 10 samples length signal with a 3 sample window and 1 sample overlap, will result in the following 4 windows:

`1:3`,`3:5`,`5:7`,`7:9`, where `m:n` represents a window including samples from `m` to `n` including the `n`th sample.

The centers for the windows would, therefore, be: `2,4,6,8`. Note that the 10th sample is not included.

It seems that MATLAB requires the maximal `number_of_windows` subjogated to `(number_of_windows-1)*hop_length+window_size<=number_of_samples`.

On the python version `liberosa.core.stft()` on the other way, t is the time of the first sample for each frame and the frames covers more than the input signal. for example, a 10 samples length signal with a 3 sample window and 2 sample hops (hops and not overlap), will result in the following 4 windows:

`1:3`,`3:5`,`5:7`,`7:9`,`9:11`, where `m:n` represents a window including samples from `m` to `n` including the `n`th sample.

The beginnings for the windows would, therefore, be: `1,3,5,7,9`. Note that the 11th non-existing sample is included.

It seems that liberosa requires the minimal `number_of_windows` subjogated to `number_of_windows*hop_length>number_of_samples`.

In my case:

(2999-1)*960+1920=2880000<=2880000 for MATLAB.
3001*960=2880960>2880000 while 30000*960=2880000 !> 2880000 in python.

Note that the times can be centered in Python by setting `center=True` flag.

This is the best explanation I could find.

Answer (score 1):

There is another issue with this topic.
In MATLAB, `stft` function is described using

```matlab
stft(x,d,'Window',win,'OverlapLength',overlap,'FFTLength',nfft);
```

where we specify a Window function (default value - `Hann(128,'periodic')`), which slides over the signal length considering the `OverlapLength` values.

In Python, `librosa.stft` is defined as

```
stftMatrix_complex = librosa.stft(data_frame, n_fft=n_fft,hop_length=hop_length_fft,win_length=win_len,window='hann',dtype=np.float64)
```

where it is mentioned that the value of `win_len` defaults to `n_fft`.

However, by changing the value of `win_length`, there is no effect on the STFT computation. The function takes the length of the `data_frame` and computes the temporal DFT bins by taking only `hop_length`.

I could not make out why this is happening.

The default value of `center=True`
Defaults to `True`, which simplifies the alignment of `D` onto a time grid by means of `librosa.frames_to_samples`.

The number of columns (time windows) in the STFT matrix is more in case of Python `librosa.stft` compared to MATLAB `stft` function.

If any one can get the answer, pls clarify. Thanks,.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35359571)